# Django get POST data posted via cURL

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm sending data using cURL like this:-

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"social_id\": \"string\",
  \"social_source\": \"FB/Gmail\",
  \"access_token\": \"string\"
}"
```

But I'm not able to get this data in my views:-

Here is my view:-

```
class UserCreate(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserCreate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        print request.POST['social_id']
```

I've tried  `request.data` as well. What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are posting a JSON blob to the server then you will not have any `POST` parameters available - those are only populated when you submit data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (e.g., using a HTML form).

You can access your JSON data as follows (from inside a view function):

```
import json
data = json.loads(request.body)
# Data is now a python dict, e.g.,
print data['social_id']
```

Comment: I tried changing headers as you described, but I still get the same error. `request.POST['social_id']` does not exisits. `curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "{
  \"social_id\": \"string\",
  \"social_source\": \"FB/Gmail\"
}" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/"`

Comment: Although  `request.body` works when header is `application/json`, but still I want to know why `request.POST` isnt working?

Comment: The first sentence of my answer explains why it isn't working: POST will only work with form encoded data, not JSON. I would suggest you learn about how HTTP POST works in general before you try to implement this.

Comment: I understand your point. But I changed the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, still its not working. Why?

Comment: Changing the header will have no effect unless you also change the format of your data being posted. Form data has a different data structure, different from JSON. The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: @PrafulBagai Try using `curl  --header 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X POST -d 'social_id=string&social_source=FBGmail&access_token=string' URL` which will generate  `request.POST` as `<QueryDict: {u'access_token': [u'string'], u'social_id': [u'string'], u'social_source': [u'FBGmail']}>`. You can even remove the headers from the curl request.